# NodeJS & Socket.io : issue with function killed by other user calls

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Hello I need some help with socket.io,

In my app, the user needs to connect to my socket.io server, then the server launches a process and sends updates about the progress to the client.
The code looks like this :

```
var MyProcess = require( './myProcess.js' );
var WebSocket = require( './class.websocket.js' );
var w = new WebSocket(8080);

w.on('connexion', function(socket){
    console.log('new client connected');
    (...)
    // client launch the process
    socket.on('process', function () {
        processAction( socket);
    });     
}); 

function processAction( socket )
{
    var f = new MyProcess();
    f.doProcess(function(percent){
        // progress received, (100 calls during 2-3mins)
        socket.emit("onProgress", percent);
    },function(){
        // process completed (only one call)
        socket.emit("onComplete");
    });
}
```

It works great for one user.
The problem is when a second user connects, the function processAction() seems to be killed or overrided. the second user receives his progress, but the first one just doesn't receive any data anymore.

[EDIT] Each user needs to receive the progress of his process only. It's like NodeJS could not handle two processAction() running at the same time. Calling it a second time is killing the previous call and the local variables inside as well.

Can you help me figure this one out ?
Thank you so much.
Anthony

Comment: Why don't you just pass the `socket` to `processAction()` as that seems to be what you want anyway?

Comment: What does `f.doProcess` do?  Does it use any globals or module state variables?

Comment: yes passing "socket" directly is easier thanks. doProcess() is actually doing long processes using Curl, so the onProgress callback will be called a bunch of time during 2-3 minutes.

Comment: My question is whether `.doProcess()` has some global state that causes conflicts when more than one socket it running at the same time.

Comment: Thank you. You're right, it's because of the global variables. I thought they were unique to the MyProcess instance, so I stored the onProgress callback there, and all other datas. but in fact they are unique to the whole application and overrided when the next user call a new instance of MyProcess. So we can't have a global variable unique to a class instance in JS ?

Comment: Your variable was unique to your module. One instance of that variable for your module. While it isn't actually global (can't be accessed from outside the module), there is still only one of them for your app so it's like a global. If you want a variable to be an instance variable in Javascript (a separate variable for each object created), then you make it a property of an object so each time one of those objects is created, you get a new and unique property for that object. The usual way to do that is to initialize a property in the constructor for a new object and then access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution (thanks to  jfriend00) is that I was doing this :

```
var onProgress;

function MyProcess(){}

MyProcess.prototype.doProcess=function( pOnProgress)
{
    onProgress = pOnProgress;
    _doProcess();
}
function _doProcess()
{
    console.log("tick");
    onProgress();
    setTimeout(_doProcess, 1000);
}
module.exports = MyProcess;
```

instead of this :

```
function MyProcess(){}

MyProcess.prototype.doProcess=function( onProgress)
{
    _doProcess(onProgress);
}
function _doProcess(onProgress)
{
    console.log("tick");
    onProgress();
    setTimeout(_doProcess, 1000, onProgress);
}
module.exports = MyProcess;
```

or this :

```
function MyProcess(){}

MyProcess.prototype.doProcess = function( onProgress)
{
    this.onProgress = onProgress;
    _doProcess(this);
}
function _doProcess(scope)
{
    console.log("tick");
    scope.onProgress();
    setTimeout(_doProcess, 1000, scope);
}
module.exports = MyProcess;
```